# Image vertical alignment for markdown files at Github

Tags: image, github, alignment, markdown

What's the best way for applying vertical alignment to images of math formulas, which are surrounded by text in a markdown files at github, e.g.

text text ![eq1][] text text

One approach I found so far, requires placing img html tag instead of ![][] markdown syntax, e.g.

text text img style="vertical-align:middle" src="https://raw.github.com/danielkorzekwa/bayes-scala/master/doc/moment_matching/eq1.png" text text

but it's not really an option, as it would make markdown file completely unreadable.

To see how github aligns images with math formulas by default, visit this page:
https://github.com/danielkorzekwa/bayes-scala/blob/master/doc/moment_matching/moment_matching.md

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to vertically align elements inside GitHub Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878670/how-to-vertically-align-elements-inside-github-markdown)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I decided to attach pdf and latex documents to my markdown file. The markdown format is not really suitable for writing math intensive documents.