# How to vertically align elements inside GitHub Markdown?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

How can I vertically align the image and text in the image below?

> [image: image followed by misaligned text]

This is the way I’m writing it in my Markdown:

```
<a name="version"></a>[ ![Download](https://api.bintray.com/packages/edsilfer/maven/search-interface/images/download.svg) ](https://bintray.com/edsilfer/maven/search-interface/_latestVersion) - **MIN API VERSION: 16**
```

Comment: This would be addressed via CSS. But GitHub doesn't allow you to define CSS on their site, so you probably can't achieve what you want.

Comment: @Waylan or others -- is this still a limitation of Github?

Comment: @KiptonBarros yes. GitHub sees that as a security issue and therefore will likely never allow users to define CSS for their site.

Answer (score 9):

I can think of 2 workarounds to this issue

1. create an image with all the text (Download 1.0.0 - MIN API 16)
2. use html for this block (ex. `<table><tr><td valign="center"><img ...> text </td></tr></table>`)

may not the best way, but it is an improvement :)

Comment: If the image has a height of 20px, it doesn't work. It works with bigger images though.

Answer (score 1):

Table example, using [Ofer Skulsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8118052/ofer-skulsky) answer suggestion:

```
<table style="width: 100%; border: none;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td rowspan="3">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

- I do not see cellspacing, cellpadding, or border having an effect on GitHub Markdown.

Here is what it looks like on a GitHub README.md:

[image]